# Mongoose findOne by 1 of 2 params

Tags: mongoose

I have following query:

```
async getIsExistingUser(hash: string) {
    const isExisting = await this.onsModel.findOne({
      salt: hash,
      emailSalt: hash,
    });

    return Boolean(isExisting);
  }
```

I want to find entity if 1 of the 2 is true, how to achieve it any idea?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mongoose findOne with 'either or' query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29098830/mongoose-findone-with-either-or-query)

Answer (score 0):

Oh nvm this one is doing the job:

```
{$or: [
    {email: req.body.email},
    {phone: req.body.phone}
]}
```